# Is it possible to refer method like property? Like Validate(x => x.Property)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, strong-typing

Because I need to build a very strongly-typed & type-safed project for Asp.net MVC. But I found that a lot of syntax in View page isn't type-safed variable. Please look at the following example.

```
BeginForm("LogOn", "Account")
```

instead of

```
Form.BeginForm(x => Account.LogOn)
```

Is it possible to create something like above code? It's a very beutiful strongly-typed sourcecode.

**Update!**

I found that it's impossible with expression tree. Please look at the following code.

Controller class that contains only 1 action.
    public class Controller1
    {
        public View Action1()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

Please look at expression code.

```
Expression<Action<Controller1>> exp1 = (c => c.Action1());

Expression part = exp1.Body;

if (part.NodeType == System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Call)
{
    MethodCallExpression callExpression = (MethodCallExpression)part;

    MessageBox.Show(callExpression.Method.DeclaringType.Name + " : " + callExpression.Method.Name);
}
```

The result is "Controller1 : Action1"!

**Update 2!**

The following code is the final code of strongly-typed begin form.

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm<BaseController>(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression<Action<BaseController>> routeExp)
{
    Expression part = routeExp.Body;

    if (part.NodeType == System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Call)
    {
        MethodCallExpression callExpression = (MethodCallExpression)part;
        MethodInfo actionMethod = callExpression.Method;

        return htmlHelper.BeginForm(actionMethod.Name, actionMethod.DeclaringType.Name);
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

So, you can call it by using the following pattern.

```
<% Html.BeginForm<HomeController>(x => x.Index()); %>
```

**Thanks,**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although lambda expressions are now possible, they are not going to help you in this case. Let's just look at your example: the BeginForm method takes two strings as input, and no amount of lambda expressions are going to change that.

You could decide to encapsulate these strings as properties on one or more classes, but it wouldn't become more *type-safe* for that reason.

It might help a bit to move all strings to a central place to reduce the risk of misspelling names, but they will still be strings.

Comment: As you say, I just try. It's possible so I will create some helper class for solving this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MVC Futures supports something like this

You can download it from [asp.net/mvc](http://asp.net/mvc) or [codeplex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) and get the source code too as a 'manual'

Warning: Being 'futures' stuff, it may change in future releases